# How to extract symbols from parsed LaTeX equation in Sympy?

Tags: python, sympy, symbols

I have parsed a LaTeX equation in Sympy, but now I need to extract the variables to symbols so that I can have Sympy solve/rearrange the equation for specific variables.

I know I can use `equation.free_symbols` to see the symbols contained in the equation, but how do I set those as symbols (automatically) so that I can specify them for the symbolic solution, i.e. `solve(equation,C_L)`?

```
from sympy.parsing.latex import parse_latex
from sympy import init_printing
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import symbols

init_printing() 

equation = parse_latex(r"""
S_{\TO} = \frac{1}{\frac{2g*\rho}{2\left( \WoS \right)}(\mu C_{\L}-C_{\D_{0}}-KC_{\L}^2)}\ln(\frac{(\ToW)-\mu + (\frac{\rho}{2(\WoS)}(\mu C_{\L}-C_{\D_{0}}-KC_{\L}^2))V_{\f}^{2}}{(\ToW)-\mu + (\frac{\rho}{2(\WoS)}(\mu C_{\L}-C_{\D_{0}}-KC_{\L}^{2}))V_{\i}^{2}} )
+ \frac{V_{\TR}^{2}}{0.2g}\sin(\sin^{-1}((\ToW)-\frac{1}{(\LoD)}))
+ \frac{h_{\obstacle}-\frac{V_{\TR}^{2}}{0.2g}(1-\cos(\gamma_{\climb}))}{\tan(\gamma_{\climb})}            
            """)

test = (equation.free_symbols)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `var` function will inject the symbols it creates from a string into the workspace. So, for example, you can do:

```py
>>> from sympy import *
>>> syms = lambda eq: tuple(ordered(var(','.join(str(i) for i in eq.free_symbols))))
>>> eq = S('x_a + Cb_1')
>>> eq.has(x_a) # not yet defined
...
NameError: name 'x_a' is not defined
>>> syms(eq)  # now x_a and Cb_1 are defined
(Cb_1, x_a)
>>> eq.has(x_a)
True
>>> esyms = syms(equation)
>>> sol = solve(equation, C_L)
```

Comment: In 'eq=S()', what does the S function due?

Comment: `S = sympify` - it creates a SymPy object from the input. I used it instead of a parse function.

Comment: Thanks. I have latex variables (i.e. C_L = latex=r"C_{L}"), how can I specify multiple latex variables like that to solve for? I.e. I want to arrange the equation such that specific variables are on the RHS.

Comment: I don't understand your question in this context. You showed one equation. You can solve it for one variable. All other symbols will be in the solution. If you don't care which variables is solved for you can list as `exlude=[list of variables you *don't* want to solve for]`.

Comment: I want to solve it symbolically for more than one variable. For example, C_L, C_D_0, and V_f. I want these variables on the LHS, and the rest on the RHS of the equation.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to provide a list of symbols to solve for, because some of them are defined as LaTeX. For example, C_L is really defined as `latex=r"C_{L}"`

Comment: What is the output of `syms(equation)`?

Comment: I can't really show here because Spyder iPython console outputs it as an image since it is LaTeX. But if I do `solve(equation,C_L)` I get an error "C_L not found" but if I do `solve(equation,latex=r"C_{L}")` there is no error (but the solving never converges)

Comment: Assign your output as `v = syms(equation)` then refer to your desired symbol by subscript, e.g. `v[2]` or whatever. I never work with `latex` symbols so I can't help much past this.

Comment: Thanks, that could work. Another problem though is that the free symbols are not always ordered the same; any way to force the same order every time the code is run?

Comment: `list(ordered(syms))` will give them in a consistent order; I will modify the syms function in the answer to do this.